# Is not & Does not with verb+ing

Tags: sentence-construction

Can we construct below sentences?

a) System does not calculating it correctly.

b) System is not calculating it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, but they should be written as follows:

> - The system does not calculate it correctly.
> - The system is not calculating it correctly.

"Is" is a present tense form of the verb *to be*, so you can use it to describe the *present state* of someone or something. "Calculating" matches that tense.

"Does", the third person singular present of *do*, denotes the *action* of something, not a state. This is why "calculate" does not need to be in the present participle.